# Can a doctest parse a function with default arguments?

Tags: elixir

The doctest fails for a function I wrote. The error message I get says that `generate_operands/0` is undefined. My intention was that the default arguments for `generate_operands/6` would be used in the doctest -- Is this possible? Is it advisable to do what I wanted or is the error intentional?

The function looks like this:

```
@doc """
Generate the operands for arithmetic practice problems.

## Examples
    iex> operands = generate_operands()
    iex> length(operands)
    10
    iex> hd(operands) |> length()
    5
"""
@spec generate_operands(
        integer,
        integer,
        boolean,
        integer,
        boolean,
        SimplePRNG.t()
      ) :: [
        [integer()],
        ...
      ]

def generate_operands(
      num_probs \\ 10,
      num_ops \\ 5,
      equal_num \\ false,
      max_power \\ 5,
      equal_mag \\ false,
      prng \\ SimplePRNGImpl
    )

def generate_operands(num_probs, num_ops, equal_num, max_power, equal_mag, prng) do
  IO.puts("generate_operands()")
end
```

The error message is:

```
== Compilation error in file test/arithmetic_practice_test.exs ==
** (CompileError) (for doctest at) lib/arithmetic_practice.ex:25: undefined function generate_operands/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:209: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

Comment: Can you also share `test/arithmetic_practice_test.exs`, as it seems fine, i tested it locally. works fine.

Comment: I'm still having trouble. Does it work when you run `mix test`? My `ArithmeticPracticeTest` module is four lines:

    defmodule ArithmeticPracticeTest do
      use ExUnit.Case
      doctest ArithmeticPractice
    end

Comment: It would be better if you can add that module also here. others also can have a very precise look.. However using the `doctest` i am also getting the issue.

Comment: Will update you in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neeed to use the full path with ModuleName to generate_operands.
Check the code below.

```
@doc """
Generate the operands for arithmetic practice problems.

## Examples
iex> operands = MyModule.InnerModule.generate_operands()
iex> length(operands)
10
iex> hd(operands) |> length()
5
"""
```

Comment: Thank you! That is so true. I forgot that was mentioned in the doctest documentation.